# References for Homotopy transfer problem

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, operads, chain-complexes

I am trying to read [Algebra+homotopy=operad](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3245.pdf) by Bruno Vallette.

Consider the following set up :

- chain complexes $(A,d_A),(H,d_H)$,
- a degree $1$ morphism of chain complexes $h:(A,d_A)\rightarrow (A,d_A)$,
- a pair of morphisms of chain complexes $p: (A,d_A)\rightarrow (H,d_H)$ and $i:(H,d_H)\rightarrow (A,d_A)$

such that $1_A-ip=d_Ah+hd_A$ (seen as a morphism of chain complexes).

Suppose further that there is an extra structure on the chain complex $(A,d_A)$, namely a morphism $v:A^{\otimes 2}\rightarrow A$ satisfying the associativity condition, that is $v(a,v(b,c))=v(v(a,b),c)$ for all $a,b,c\in A$. It is not mentioned explicitly, but I am assuming this $v$ is a collection $\{v_{n,m}:A_n\otimes A_m\rightarrow A_{n+m}\}$. Further, it is assumed that the differential $d_A$ is a derivation for the product.

Now, consider the composition $p\circ v\circ (i_n\otimes i_m):H_n\otimes H_m\rightarrow H_{n+m}$.

One question is if these collection $\{p\circ v\circ (i_n\otimes i_m)\}_{n,m\in \mathbb{Z}}$ combine to give an associative algebra structure on the chain complex $(H,d_H)$. This is what is called (at least what I think) the Homotopy transfer problem. It turns out that this does not give an associative algebra structure but this gives some identities that forms what is called an $A_\infty$-algebra. This is how they introduce  $A_\infty$-algebra.

I am having trouble understanding the intuition behind those identities. This could be because I don’t have sufficient background.

Can some one suggest some references that starts from scratch on this Homotopy transfer problem?

Comment: I do agree this is not a research level problem. But, this is also not suitable for MSE :)

Comment: In my opinion, A-infinity algebra structure on a graded vector space $V$  _is_ a choice of a differential on tensor coalgebra $T(sV)$. All intricate and meaningless "higher associativity" identities are homogenous components of a statement that differential squares to zero. In original topological setting (I highly recommend reading "Homotopy associative H-spaces" by Jim Stasheff which was the starting point of this whole story) those higher associators made a lot of sense, but when you take chains and try to emulate all this verbatim they turn into a total mess.

Comment: @DenisT. then why do we still work in that format? :)

Comment: Well, there are cases when explicit identities are important, and there are some people who are really good with this kind of algebraic combinatorics, and can prove a lot of interesting things in this framework. So, this approach is meaningless (non-conceptual), but dfinitely not useless. It happened that most influential papers (Kadeishvili, Loday etc) on the subject were written before Koszul duality (tag for search) approach was estabilished, and people got used to work with A-infty objects "in coordinates". So, just a case of notation inertia.

Comment: @DenisT. Ok. Do you have any personal choice of paper that has some details about this Homotopy transfer problem or $A_\infty$ algebras (other than the paper of Jim Stasheff that you already mentioned)?

Comment: Markl https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401007 ?

Comment: @DashaPoliakova Hi, thanks for the reference. I have not seen that before. I will see that now..